# Editing text using awk or sed in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

The content of my `file.txt` is something like this:

```
fghfg
sdfsd
thrt
wefs
dfd
htyj
dfd
gsedf
     1     sdfsdf
     3     sdfghj
     f     fgdfhtyu
dfdsfsd
sdgdfg
sdfzcxzc
fgjty
```

I want to change this part:

```
1     sdfsdf
3     sdfghj
f     fgdfhtyu
```

to this one: (by removing first column and spaces)

```
sdfsdf
sdfghj
fgdfhtyu
```

Then redirect the whole output of `file.txt` to `file2.txt`.

How is it possible...?

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't very clear.  What do you mean by _reaches to this pattern_?

Comment: I mean just remove that first column..

Comment: Yes...I removed duplicate by this command `awk '!a[$0]++' "$line"` ..Thank you

Comment: The question isn't still clear.  `awk '{print $NF}' filename` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: ok forget about it...may be I am wrong...please help me for doing this one..I updated my question again..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '{print $NF}' file.txt > file2.txt
```

or shortest solution of the day:

```
awk '{$0=$NF}1' file.txt > file2.txt
cat file2.txt
fghfg
sdfsd
thrt
wefs
dfd
htyj
dfd
gsedf
sdfsdf
sdfghj
fgdfhtyu
dfdsfsd
sdgdfg
sdfzcxzc
fgjty
```

Just print the last column.

Comment: @MortezaLSC You cold use `awk '$0=$NF'`, but its not robust and will delete empty lines.  I do also like `awk` better than  `sed`, since it s much more readable.

Comment: Of course you are right... I don't know why I couldn't solve it... I lost my concentration :)

Comment: `awk '$0=$NF'` wouldn't only delete empty lines, it'd also delete lines that are a string that numerically evaluates to zero, e.g. `0`, `0.0`, `0e10`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your script to this:

```
find "$1" -print |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    awk '!a[$0]++{print $NF}' "$line" > /tmp/file.txt
done
```

Does anything need to change?

Answer (score 2):

Using *sed*, you can do something like this

```
sed 's/^ \+[^ ] \+//' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

It will remove all sequences at the begining of the line that contain a sequence of whitespaces, followed by a single non whitespace character than a sequence of whitespaces. Using the file in your question, the results is:

```
fghfg
sdfsd
thrt
wefs
dfd
htyj
dfd
gsedf
sdfsdf
sdfghj
fgdfhtyu
dfdsfsd
sdgdfg
sdfzcxzc
fgjty
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple `sed` command,

```
sed 's/.* \(.*\)/\1/g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: @Mortez Try this `sed 's/.* \(.*\)/\1/g;s/\(.*\)/test:\1/g' file1.txt > file2.txt`